Inequality of Young type
How can we show that for any $1<r<p$ and any $a,b,c,d>0$ the following inequality holds:
$$\left [1+(r-1)\left (\frac{a}{b} \right )^r \right ]c^p+\left [1+(r-1)\left (\frac{b}{a} \right )^r \right ]d^p\geq r\left (\dfrac{a}{b} \right )^{r-1}c^{p-1}d+r\left (\frac{b}{a} \right )^{r-1}cd^{p-1}$$
?
I tried to apply Young inequality for products but I'm having problems in analyzing the situations in which the numbers $c,d$ are in $(0,1)$ or $(1,\infty)$ where the monotony of the exponential function changes.
I showed that equality takes place when $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{d}{c}$. Here it is important that $r<p$.

To reduce the number of variables, one can replace $\dfrac a b$ by $x$ and $\dfrac b a$ by $\dfrac 1 x$.

First we write
$$
r\left(\dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{r-1}c^{p-1}d+r\left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^{r-1}cd^{p-1} = r \left(\dfrac{ac}{b} \right)^{r-1}c^{p-r}d+r\left(\frac{bd}{a} \right)^{r-1}cd^{p-r},
$$
then we use Young's inequality with $r$ and its Hölder conjugate $\frac{r}{r-1}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left (\dfrac{ac}{b} \right )^{r-1}d &\leq \frac{r-1}{r}\left (\dfrac{ac}{b} \right )^{r} + \frac{d^r}{r},\\
\left (\dfrac{bd}{a} \right )^{r-1}c &\leq \frac{r-1}{r}\left (\dfrac{bd}{a} \right )^{r} + \frac{c^r}{r}.
\end{align}
$$
This gives us
$$
r \left(\dfrac{ac}{b} \right)^{r-1}c^{p-r}d+r\left(\frac{bd}{a} \right)^{r-1}cd^{p-r} \leq (r-1)\left(\dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{r}c^p + c^{p-r}d^r + (r-1)\left(\dfrac{b}{a} \right)^{r}d^p + d^{p-r}c^r,
$$
so all that remains to show is that
$$
 c^{p-r}d^r + d^{p-r}c^r \leq c^p + d^p,
$$
which is easy to see since the difference factors nicely:
$$
c^p + d^{p} - c^{p-r}d^r - d^{p-r}c^r = (c^{p-r} - d^{p-r})(c^r - d^r) \geq 0.
$$
Here the nonnegativity follows from the fact that the factors must have the same sign (and that's where we need $p \geq r$).
Combining everything we get
$$
\begin{align}
r\left(\dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{r-1}c^{p-1}d+r\left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^{r-1}cd^{p-1} &\leq  (r-1)\left(\dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{r}c^p + c^{p} + (r-1)\left(\dfrac{b}{a} \right)^{r}d^p + d^{p}\\
&= \left [1+(r-1)\left (\frac{a}{b} \right )^r \right ]c^p+\left [1+(r-1)\left (\frac{b}{a} \right )^r \right ]d^p.
\end{align}
$$
